# How to manage Typo3 multisite domains?

Tags: typo3, multisite, typo3-11.x

Two questions about Typo3 Multisite concept:

1- Is it wise to keep main installation (I believe this is called “network” in Typo3 concept) on a kind of special domain which is not used for content like: “typo3panel.example.com” and have different domains for each different root pages (i.e. “site” in Typo3 concept)?

2- How is different subdomains and domains managed in Typo3 multisite environment? Like for example I have added a root page (a site) and created the configuration for it with the entry point “business.com” and added another site for “brand.anotherbusiness.com”. Now how do I set this “business.com” and “brand.anotherbusiness.com” in terms of “network” to allow them to resolve to corresponding Typo3 site? For example how should I set the DNS records of those domains and what should I do more on Typo3 side? Because I can't seem to map the domains for the multisite environment and official docs do not cover it. I wonder if it's done through adding domain aliases?

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the docs about "site handling", which covers how to define rootpages and entry points. That's the way, how to configure multisites in TYPO3: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html

Comment: No, it's not covered in the document. No where in the document it mentions how you need to setup the domains. Defining root pages and entry points are ok. But how the other domain will actually resolve to this Typo3 instance?

Comment: Setting up a domain (and DNS, as you mentioned in your post) is not part of the application running on a webserver but part of configuring the webserver itself. So, of course, it's not documented in the applications docs...

Comment: Fair point; but if it is required to make the application work, then I think it should mention it somehow. I mean what's the point of multisite if it's not known how to point multiple domains to one instance? Your point would be more sound if it was a standard process; but I guess there is something application-specific here.

Comment: Pointing multiple domains to one vhost is standard of configuring a webserver and part of the webserver configuration. For Apache this would be `ServerAlias` for example (but there are other ways, too). For nginx, you have to add the list of domains as `server_name`.
Handling different domains in same vhost in a different way, *that* is part of the webapplication. And that's the documented Site Handling.

Comment: Thank you. I think that should also be achievable via DNS, but pointing the domain to Typo3 network doesn't do the trick. Also pointing to Typo3 main installation URL via CNAME also doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly means "doesn't work"? Can you reach any kind of static content under the domain? E.g. some PDF in `/fileadmin`? if not, it's an issue of DNS/webserver. If you can't call pages, it's an issue of TYPO3 - but then any kind of error message would be helpful.

Comment: Here is how I am doing;

1- Install Typo3 instance to typo3.example.com
2- Create a new A record on example.com like demo.example.com which points to the same IP which resolves to typo3.example.com
3- Create a site in Typo3 panel whose entry point is demo.example.com

This way, demo.example.com/test-page resolves to main domain which is hosted on the same server. Like anotherdomain.com/test-page. This is a VPS managed with Plesk panel. (That of course produces a 404 error.)

Comment: Now as another approach;

4- Instead of creating an A record for example.com, I try creating a new subdomain in Plesk with the name demo.example.com pointing to the same physical directory of typoe3.example.com (i.e. not having its own public directory). This time browser says "too many redirections" for demo.example.com and it won't load.

Comment: Back to webserver configuration (as DNS is network *before* the server, and TYPO3 would be *after* the server): you have the two domains typo3.example.com and demo.example.com. Can you call demo.example.com/typo3/ and typo3.example.com/typo3/ respectively demo.example.com/fileadmin/anyFile.pdf  typo3.example.com/fileadmin/anyFile.pdf ?

Comment: Now I used "additional directives" in Plesk to add "ServerAlias" in typo3.example.com to include demo.example.com and deleted physical subdomain plus the DNS record. And re-created site configuration in Typo3 panel and a new (home/main) page just some text in it. Now demo.example.com resolves to Typo3 instance correctly, but it produces HTTP 500 on the front page. Looks like multisite problem is resolved but introduced a new problem which will need to involve me learning to administrate Typo3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247121/discussion-between-turab-and-julian-hofmann).

Answer (score 0):

The site configuration of TYPO3 can deal with so called baseVariants, which can be triggered by conditions. i.e. to get different domains and behvaiours for production or development sites.

But of course you can use other conditions too:

```
base: 'https://my-domain.de/'
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://my-domain.com/'
    condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "my-domain.com"'
  -
    base: 'https://my_subdomain.my-domain.de/'
    condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "my_subdomain.my-domain.de"'
  -
    base: 'https://my_subdomain.my-domain.com/'
    condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "my_subdomain.my-domain.com"'
```

Within your TypoScript you could then remove any fixed domains by using

```
config {
  absRefPrefix = /
  absRelPath = /
}
```

So any domain would be handled the same way.

Still it's questionable if this is a good approach, since it will lead to double content penalties on Google. So you have to make sure to add proper canonical configurations too.

IMHO it would be better to redirect domains already on the webserver but after all that might be a matter of taste.